# Q-Q plot with ggplot2::stat_qq, colours, single group

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm looking for a more convenient way to get a Q-Q plot in `ggplot2` where the quantiles are computed for the data set as a whole. but I can use mappings (colour/shapes) for groups in the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(broom) ## for augment()
```

Make up some data:

```
set.seed(1001)
N <- 1000
G <- 10
dd <- data_frame(x=runif(N),
             f=factor(sample(1:G,size=N,replace=TRUE)),
             y=rnorm(N)+2*x+as.numeric(f))
m1 <- lm(y~x,data=dd)
dda <- cbind(augment(m1),f=dd$f)
```

Basic plot:

```
ggplot(dda)+stat_qq(aes(sample=.resid))
```

[image]

if I try to add colour, the groups get separated for the quantile computation (which I don't want):

```
ggplot(dda)+stat_qq(aes(sample=y,colour=f))
```

[image]

If I use `stat_qq(aes(sample=y,colour=f,group=1))` ggplot ignores the colour specification and I get the first plot back.

I want a plot where the points are positioned as in the first case, but coloured as in the second case. I have a `qqnorm`-based manual solution that I can post but am looking for something nicer ...

Comment: I don't think the data set you used in this question was generated with the correct seed. Note where your second and third largest sample points are relative to the answer, which is also what I got when running your code. Can you fix this? I found it confusing and initially thought the answer given below was incorrect.

Comment: better now .... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could calculate the quantiles yourself and then plot using `geom_point`:

```
dda = cbind(dda, setNames(qqnorm(dda$.resid, plot.it=FALSE), c("Theoretical", "Sample")))

ggplot(dda) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Theoretical, y=Sample, colour=f))
```

[image]

Ah, I guess I should have read to the end of your question. This is the manual solution you were referring to, right? Although you could just package it as a function:

```
my_stat_qq = function(data, colour.var) {

  data=cbind(data, setNames(qqnorm(data$.resid, plot.it=FALSE), c("Theoretical", "Sample")))

  ggplot(data) + 
    geom_point(aes_string(x="Theoretical", y="Sample", colour=colour.var))

}

my_stat_qq(dda, "f")
```

Comment: yes, that's the manual solution I was referring to (yours is slightly better than mine).

Comment: Nicely done. I used the top one.  It smells like a hack, but it does the job and "good enough" is, by definition, good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a ggproto-based approach that attempts to change `StatQq`, since the underlying issue here (colour specification gets ignored when group is specified explicitly) is due to how its `compute_group` function is coded.

1. Define alternate version of `StatQq` with modified `compute_group` (last few lines of code):

```
StatQq2 <- ggproto("StatQq", Stat,
                  default_aes = aes(y = after_stat(sample), x = after_stat(theoretical)),
                  
                  required_aes = c("sample"),
                  
                  compute_group = function(data, scales, quantiles = NULL,
                                           distribution = stats::qnorm, dparams = list(),
                                           na.rm = FALSE) {

                    sample <- sort(data$sample)
                    n <- length(sample)
                    
                    # Compute theoretical quantiles
                    if (is.null(quantiles)) {
                      quantiles <- stats::ppoints(n)
                    } else if (length(quantiles) != n) {
                      abort("length of quantiles must match length of data")
                    }
                    
                    theoretical <- do.call(distribution, c(list(p = quote(quantiles)), dparams))
                    
                    res <- ggplot2:::new_data_frame(list(sample = sample, 
                                                         theoretical = theoretical))
                    
                    # NEW: append remaining columns from original data 
                    # (e.g. if there were other aesthetic variables),
                    # instead of returning res directly
                    data.new <- subset(data[rank(data$sample), ], 
                                       select = -c(sample, PANEL, group))
                    if(ncol(data.new) > 0) res <- cbind(res, data.new)

                    res
                  }
)
```

2. Define `geom_qq2` / `stat_qq2` to use modified `StatQq2` instead of `StatQq` for their stat:

```
geom_qq2 <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "point", 
                      position = "identity", ..., distribution = stats::qnorm, 
                      dparams = list(), na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                      inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = StatQq2, geom = geom, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(distribution = distribution, dparams = dparams, 
                      na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}

stat_qq2 <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "point", 
                      position = "identity", ..., distribution = stats::qnorm, 
                      dparams = list(), na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                      inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = StatQq2, geom = geom, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(distribution = distribution, dparams = dparams, 
                      na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

Usage:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(
  ggplot(dda) + stat_qq(aes(sample = .resid)),        # original
  ggplot(dda) + stat_qq2(aes(sample = .resid,         # new
                             color = f, group = 1))
)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Although I feel very awkward to question one of your answers, I am not sure if this is resulting in the desired output - I think it should in the end look more like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42679222/7941188) ?