# How to color points and provide a figure key in a QQ plot using qqplotr::stat_qq_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using `qqplotr::stat_qq_point()` which is an "add-on" to ggplot2 to display a quantile-quantile plot. I would like to color the points by a grouping factor and also provide a figure key. I would also like to include a 95% CI band and fit line. One coherent way to do these tasks is to use `ggplot2`, `stat_qq_band` (CI from `qqplotr`), `stat_qq_line` (best fit line in both `ggplot2` and `qqplotr`) and `stat_qq_point` (plotted qq points from `qqplotr`). However, I cannot work out how to present the figure key.

In my code (below) have omitted the 95% CI and fit line, as they can be easily added afterwards. The code provides correctly colored points, but no legend.

I know that my code is very kludgy. If I understand correctly, `aes` in `stat_qq_point` only accepts the`sample` parameter and does not accept `colour`. This means that the normal strategies to provide colour and figure legends for plots of data points are not available.

[I found a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678858/q-q-plot-with-ggplot2stat-qq-colours-single-group)

However, the previous question and answer is a little bit of a "hack". The strategy proposed in the previous question is to not use `stat_qq_point` but rather to calculate the quantiles separately using the base function `qqnorm`. The ggplot function `geom_point` can then be used with its attendant abilities to color points individually and provide a figure key.

sample data from the other question:

```
set.seed(1001)
N <- 1000
G <- 10
dd <- data_frame(x=runif(N),
         f=factor(sample(1:G,size=N,replace=TRUE)),
         y=rnorm(N)+2*x+as.numeric(f))
m1 <- lm(y~x,data=dd)
dda <- cbind(augment(m1),f=dd$f)
```

Using these data with my approach is as follows:

```
gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
  hues = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
  hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
}

n = length(unique(dda$f))
colores_1 = gg_color_hue(n)
dda$Color <- colores_1[dda$f]

dda$theory_quant=qqnorm(dda$.resid,plot.it=FALSE)$x
dda$sample_quant=qqnorm(dda$.resid,plot.it=FALSE)$y

library(qqplotr)

ggplot() +
stat_qq_point(
    data = dda, 
    mapping = aes(sample = .resid),
    colour=dda$Color
) +
scale_colour_manual(
    values=unique(dda$Colour),
    name ="f", 
    labels=c(1:10)
) +
guides(
    colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill=NA),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
     ) +
labs(x = "Theoretical Quantiles", y = "Sample Quantiles")
```

And yields the following, which has colored points but no figure key:

[image: ![Plot of quantiles colored by f]

So, in sum, I would like an approach to draw qq plots with points colored by groupings, a best fit line, 95% CI and figure key using ggplot2 and its "add-on" `qqplotr`. But perhaps it is simply not possible to do all of these tasks uing `qqplotr`.

I thought it would be of value to leave my question on SO, in case any better approaches have emerged in the previous 1.8 years since the previous question was asked.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks very much @Tjebo for your comments and fully understand that you do not mean to adversely criticize. The reason I would like for the points to be on the same graph, if possible, is (1) The residuals are from a mixed model with group as a random effect. It would be nice if all the points were on the same graph but colored differently to show that batch effects of group have been decreased/removed by the model. (2) I would like to present a number of these qq plots and it would be more compact (by six-fold -- the number of groups) to have the groups on one graph.

Comment: Yes, you are quite correct @Tjebo that using my code with `stat_qq_point()` gives the same results as @BenBolker, except my code has no legend. In summary: my code using `stat_qq_point()` can be used more seamlessly with stat_qq_band() and stat_qq_line() to give an intellectually coherent qq plot. My code, however, provides no legend. Ben's code uses its own qq calculations to "graft" `geom_point()` onto ggplot, which conceptually forces a square peg into a round hole. However, Ben's strategy does work nicely and provides a figure key. I just wondered if there was a more "ggploty" way.

Comment: have seen and removed some of the other bits of the question. It's getting there :D You could delete some of your comments here, for clarity, and I think I'll have a look at it tomorrow or on Saturday, seems like a fun problem.

Comment: I don't think it's possible the way you want it - the problem is when you are defining colors outside of aes, you won't get a legend. [see e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511911/difference-between-passing-options-in-aes-and-outside-of-it-in-ggplot2) I think the solution provided by @eipi10 is probably the most straight forward - and actually comparatively *very* straightforward without much 'hack' ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for your efforts @Tjebo! Yes, I agree that it seems my approach will simply not be successful for the reasons you describe. Would you mind awfully posting your comment as an answer, which I could accept? Thanks again!